# bootstrap-table: how to nest one table into another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-table

I'm using this [bootstrap-table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/). I'd like to nest one table into another.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var t = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "john",
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "ted"
  }];


  //TABLE 1
  $('#summaryTable').bootstrapTable({
    data: t,
    detailFormatter: detailFormatter
  });

  function detailFormatter(index, row, element) {
    $(element).html(row.name);
    $(element).html(function() {
      //I was thinking of putting the code here, but I don't know how to do it so it will work,
      //except javascript, it needs to be put this html code <table id="detailTable"></table>

    });


    //   return [

    //    ].join('');
  }

  //TABLE 2
  var t2 = [{
    "id": "1",
    "shopping": "bike",
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "shopping": "car"
  }];
  $('#detailTable').bootstrapTable({
    data: t2,
    columns: [{
      field: 'id',
      title: 'id'
    }, {
      field: 'shopping',
      title: 'Shopping detail'
    }, {
      field: 'status',
      checkbox: true
    }],
    checkboxHeader: false

  });
  $('#detailTable').on('check.bs.table', function(e, row, $el) {
    alert('check index: ' + row.shopping);
  });
  $('#detailTable').on('uncheck.bs.table', function(e, row, $el) {
    alert('uncheck index: ' + row.shopping);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.0/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.0/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>



<div class="container">
  <p>TABLE 1</p>
  <table id="summaryTable" data-detail-view="true">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th data-field="id" data-align="center" data-width="20px">id</th>
        <th data-field="name" data-align="center">Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
  <br>

  <p>TABLE 2</p>
  <table id="detailTable"></table>

</div>
```

*Here is the link of my demo: **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fjykowtL/)***

There are two tables. Table 1 has expandable rows and I want to put Table 2 into every row of table 1. There is this function called [detailFormatter](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/#table-options) which does this and where you can return a string or render an element (I was playing with it, but I can't make it work). For this demo the table 1 is created with some html code and the table 2 uses only javascript, but there is this initiating div `<table id="detailTable"></table>` (it doesn't matter for me which way is done). **So, the question is how to put the table 2 into table 1 with possibility of using its events (like check or uncheck checkbox) as the demo shows for table2?** Later on, I'd like to use this event `onExpandRow` so when the user expands the row of table 1 it will get the data from a database and it'll fill out the table 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well just clone your `detailTable` and put it in each `row` with `detailFormatter` as below:

```
function detailFormatter(index, row, element) {
    $(element).html($('#detailTable').clone(true));
}
```

Now there will be duplicate `id`'s created when you do `clone`, so you just remove it by changing its `id` as below:

```
function detailFormatter(index, row, element) {
     $(element).html($('#detailTable').clone(true).attr('id',"tbl_"+row.id));
}
```

Also, you can hide the `#detailTable` since you are just having it to append it in another `table` and once you hide it you need to add `show` to `cloned tables` as all the properties will be copied to in `clone(true)` which can be done as below:

```
function detailFormatter(index, row, element) {
    $(element).html($('#detailTable').clone(true).attr('id',"tbl_"+row.id).show());
}
//.....
//.....
//.....
//At the end
$("#detailTable").hide();
```

**[A complete DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/fjykowtL/2/)**

Comment: thank you. It works for me. I just needed to put Table 2 into Div to remove this line under the Table 1 and make restriction with one open row at the time, so the user won't check a checkbox in two different opened rows. I have 2 more questions about css. How to make `padding:0` only for table 2? and how to change the row background-color for the Table 1 where the row is expanded and after it collapses get back old color? [updated demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fjykowtL/3/) I've added `expand-row` function and some CSS code.

Comment: exactly, thanks again, what about the first question? The table 2 is placed with 8px padding and I found out that the line `.bootstrap-table .table:not(.table-condensed) > tbody > tr > td ` in bootstrap-table.css causes this behavior but If I try to overwrite it then it has influence for the whole table 1 and 2.

Comment: You can give a extra `class` name to your 2nd table and write you extra `CSS` on that class.. however it will be copied with `clone`.. **[`Something like this`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/fjykowtL/5/)**

Comment: I don't see any effect, I noticed you have added a class, but table 2 is still with 8px padding around it.

Comment: How about **[`this`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/fjykowtL/6/)**.. I've added ``tr.detail-view>td {
  padding:0 !important;  //it has influence on everything 
}` replaced your issue creating `css` i.e. which effects for all the `tds`

Comment: Great! Thank you. So, there is no need to use this extra class `specialTable`.

Comment: One more thing, please check the [this link](https://jsfiddle.net/fjykowtL/7/) I've added a confirmation dialog, and I'm trying to uncheck the checkbox when user clicks cancel button, but it doesn't work for the cloned table. More comments in the code.

Comment: @soonic I would suggest you to create a separate question for this because I've already answered more than 2 to 3 questions within a question and its against SO policies.. :)

Comment: I can create a separate question, but I thought that this one is very related to your root answer, so I wanted to keep around one topic. This one last? :)

Comment: Sorry buddy.. I din want to stay without replying. I tried my best on this part, but honestly couldn't get it done for you. Do post it as a separate question and am sure you will get n number of ppl to solve it.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found another way of nesting one table into another using (partly) dynamic table creation (referring to my posted question when using bootstrap-table).

```
var expandedRow = row.id;
$(element).html(
    "<table id='detailTable"+expandedRow+"'><thead><tr><th data-field='id2' data-align='center' data-width='20px'>id2</th>" +
    "<th data-field='shopping' data-align='center'>Shopping detail</th>" +
    "<th data-field='status' data-checkbox='true'></th>" +
    "</tr></thead></table>");

$('#detailTable'+expandedRow).bootstrapTable({
  data: t2,
  checkboxHeader: false
});
```

I think this way is more independent. There is no need to have one panel opened at the time. The events and methods seems to be working fine.

[Full code here.](https://jsfiddle.net/apwmc9pp/)